# Regex string tokenizing

Tags: regex, drupal

I'm trying to set up a regex search tokenizer in Drupal and need some regex help.
How should I set a Whitespace characters (word delimiter regex) so that it tokenizes mixed strings, and so both strings: `ABC-1` and `ABC1` will be divided into `ABC` an `1` substrings. Currently the regex is: `[^\p{L}\p{N}^']` but does not seem to be appropriate. How can I mix in a hyphen into this negated class so that it becomes a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

Use **regex** `/([^\sa-z\-]+|[^\s0-9\-]+)/ig`

[ *Test: http://ideone.com/44Wxy* ]

Comment: Thanks. While the test performs OK, the implementation of the regex in Drupal fails at this one. I think I have to use character class only, such as when you use in Javascript `String.split(/[delimiters]+/)` to tokenize a string